# conversion from java sql date to java localdate

Tags: java, datetime, time

```
    String oldDate = "04-07-19 02:41:39.063000000 PM";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("dd-MM-YY HH:mm:ss")
                .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 1, 9, true)
                .padNext(1)
                .appendText(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY)
                .toFormatter();

LocalDate parseDate = LocalDate.parse(oldDate, formatter);
```

My date from the DB is "04-07-19 02:41:39.063000000 PM"
and i want to parse the date and convert it to my convenient form.
but when i try to parse the date using the DateTimeFormatter  mentioned above the code throws exception..

the new date should be of the format mentioned below

```
String newDate = parseDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMMM-uuuu"));
```

can someone help me to track the error?

exception iam getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '04-07-19 02:41:39.063000000 PM' could not be parsed at index 55
```

Comment: "code throws exception.." and our task is to guess what is that exception? Why didn't you put it in your question?

Comment: Do you store the date on DB in a varchar or date? Why are you parsing text  in your example? Couldn't you get ` java.sql.Date` from the DB?

Comment: i have updated the the question to add the exception..i did not try any other workaround but iam just curious why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pattern you had few errors. First of all `padNext()` add a padding **to** a fixed width. In your case it should be 28 or something like that. I've just replaced it with `appendLiteral(' ')`. Then `HH` represends hours in 24hour day, it won't work with AM/PM. Last thing was year, `YY` represends "week-based-year" according to JavaDoc (not exactly sure what that means) - had to change to `yy` for it to work.

Working pattern:

```
    String oldDate = "04-07-19 02:41:39.063000000 PM";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss")
                .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 1, 9, true)
                .appendLiteral(' ')
                .appendText(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY)
                .toFormatter();

    LocalDate parseDate = LocalDate.parse(oldDate, formatter);
    System.out.println(parseDate);
```

Comment: This is correct, I was about to post the same thing

Comment: Thank you Amongalen.. i was trying this since morning.. learned a lot of things from our answer..Great